# how to make the most recent element of the list active and pass and display the row data of the list

Tags: angular

[image: picture of survey list(2nd one) while displayed data is of 1st survey][image][image][image]

Edit: after making some changes in ngOnInit, I am able to see the data when I debug, but still it is not working properly.
 it is highlighting 2nd survey  while displaying 1st survey data and not the first one. although index in both case  is zero.
ngOnInit's content now look like this.

```
this._service.getSurveyData().subscribe(data => {
                   this.surveyData = data;
                   console.log(this.surveyData);
                   this.surveySummary = this.surveyData.details;
                   console.log(this.surveySummary);
                   if(this.surveyData) {
                     console.log("77777777")
                    this.itemClicked[0] = true; // for default highlight
                    this.getSurveyDetail(this.surveyData[0].id, this.surveyData[0].i[![enter image description here][4]][4]d);
                   }

                 }, error => {
                   console.log("error");
                 });
```

When I login, I get a list of surveys which I am displaying in the list. On clicking of any row of the list, I am passing survey ID then in my component, I am comparing survey ID of row and surveyID which is in JSON, and then fetching the data. however I have to display first row data by default.
Once approach which Timothy has proposed but unfortunately it is not working the way it should. the error which I am getting is " Cannot read property '0' of undefined" when I am calling method of getSurveyDettail inside ngOnInit although I am calling surveyList inside constructor which comes before ngOnInit.

Survey list was undefined so I called the function again which was in the service and subscribe to the data so that it become available but it is simply skipping the if(this.surveyData) condition.

```js
itemClicked: boolean[] = [];
  surveyDetail;
  surveyData;
  chartData;
  surveySummary;
  surveyDefaultLayout;
constructor(public _service: SurveyInfoService) 
     this.getSurveyData();

  }

ngOnInit() {
this._service.getSurveyData().subscribe(data => {
                   this.surveyData = data;
                   console.log(this.surveyData);
                   this.surveySummary = this.surveyData.details;
                   console.log(this.surveySummary);
                 }, error => {
                   console.log("error");
                 });
                 if(this.surveyData) {
               this.itemClicked[0] = true; // for default highlight
               this.getSurveyDetail(this.surveyData[0].surveyId, this.surveyData[0].surveyId);
                 };

}

  getSurveyData() {
    this._service.getSurveyData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.surveyData = data;
        console.log(this.surveyData);
        this.surveySummary = this.surveyData.details;
        console.log(this.surveySummary);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("error");
      }
    );
  }
}
      getSurveyDetail(surveyId, index) {
    this.itemClicked.fill(false);
    this.itemClicked[index] = true;
    console.log(this.surveyData);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.surveyData.length; i++) {
      if (this.surveyData[i].id === surveyId) {
        this.surveyDetail = this.surveyData[i].details;
        this.surveyDefaultLayout = this.surveyData[i]['defaultArrayLayout'];
        this.chartData = this.surveyData[i].columnChart;
        console.log(
          this.surveyDetail,
          this.surveyDefaultLayout,
          this.chartData
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
    <li [ngClass]="{'list-group-item row-highlight': itemClicked[i]}" *ngFor="let item of surveyData; let i=index;" (click)="getSurveyDetail(item.id,i)">{{item.item}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: when you login, assign the 1st row data i:e surveyData[0] to your respective default data variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ngOnInit()` , after you get the necessary data i.e. surveylist/surveyData ,
Call the method `getSurveyDetail(surveyData[0].surveyId,0)`
Use this data to bind in template and where you want to show the default data, also highlight that list item as per you choice (write a css class)

```
.row-highlight{

 background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

Use this class in your template for

```
<li [ngClass]="{'list-group-item row-highlight': itemClicked[i]}"  *ngFor="let item of surveyData; let i=index;" (click)="getSurveyDetail(item.id)">{{item.item}}</li>
```

Assign these booleans in your component class

```
itemClicked : boolean []=[];
```

in `ngOnInit()` 
set `itemClicked[0]=true;//for default highlight`

And on click method set the boolean of that index as true

```
getSurveyDetail(surveyId , index) {
     //reset previous clicks
     itemClicked.fill(false);
     //and set that index as true
     itemClicked [index]=true;
    console.log(this.surveyData);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.surveyData.length; i++) {
      if (this.surveyData[i].id === surveyId) {
        this.surveyDetail = this.surveyData[i].details;
        this.surveyDefaultLayout = this.surveyData[i]['defaultArrayLayout'];
        this.chartData = this.surveyData[i].columnChart;
        console.log(this.surveyDetail,this.surveyDefaultLayout, this.chartData);
      }
    }
  }
```

Also you will need to modify the call `(click)="getSurveyDetail(item.id)"`
as `(click)="getSurveyDetail(item.id,i)"`

Comment: there is parameter mismatch as in ngOnInit, getSurveyDetail(surveyData[0].surveyId) includes only one parameter while getSurveyDetail(surveyId , index) expect two parameter also this array.fills is showing error as these are those two errors. ERROR in E:/shekhar/mySun/src/app/surveys/components/surveys-info/surveys-info.component.ts (57,5): Cannot find name 'Arrays'.
ERROR in E:/shekhar/mySun/src/app/surveys/components/surveys-info/surveys-info.component.ts (78,5): Supplied parameters do not match any signat
ure of call target.

Comment: You can modify the call from ngoninit as getSurveyDetail(surveyData[0].surveyId,0) ,, this will make sure it is for index 0

Comment: yeah, this will solve parameter mismatch problem but  Array.fills is also throwing some error.

Comment: edited my answer , my typescript is little rusty but i think it should work now

Comment: No buddy, it is not working properly, the error which I am getting is Cannot read property '0' of undefined   when I am calling
               this.getSurveyDetail(this.surveyData[0].surveyId, this.surveyData[0].surveyId); although I am calling surveyList inside constructor which comes before ngOnInit.

Comment: Hey, I can't give you line by line code :-). But i can point out that you need to take care of async calling and subscribe to an observable when the data is available. Like , make getSurveyData()  as to only return Observable and subscribe to it from where it is being called, and then once the data is available, then only use  getSurveyDetail(surveyData[0].surveyId,0)

Comment: I have edited the question. now able to use  getSurveyDetail(surveyData[0].surveyId,0) when the data is available but it is highlighting and displaying 2nd survey and not the first one. although index is zero.